# How to get the name of a geometry node tree created using a script?

Tags: python, scripting, geometry-nodes

I wanted to create a geometry node tree using my script and modify this tree. As I understand, you need the name of the tree to edit it.

I tried assigning `bpy.ops.node.new_geometry_nodes_modifier()` to a variable, but this function just returns `{'FINISHED'}`. Moreover, I cannot supply a name to the geometry node tree using `bpy.ops.node.new_geometry_nodes_modifier()` because it does not have a `name` argument. Is there a way to get the name of this newly created tree?

Kind regards,
Rohit

Comment: You can create a modifier without an op: `ob.modifiers.new("My Modifier Name", 'NODES')`. This returns the new modifier.

Answer (score 3):

Use the low-level function to add modifiers: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ObjectModifiers.html#bpy.types.ObjectModifiers.new

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.scene.objects['Cube']
geo_mod = obj.modifiers.new(name="GeometryNodes", type='NODES')

print(geo_mod.name, geo_mod)
# GeometryNodes <bpy_struct, NodesModifier("GeometryNodes") at 0x600000518a58>
```

`NodesModifier.node_group` returns the node tree: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.NodesModifier.html#bpy.types.NodesModifier.node_group

```
tree = geo_mod.node_group
nodes = tree.nodes

for n in nodes:
    print(n.name, n)

# Group Output <bpy_struct, NodeGroupOutput("Group Output") at 0x7fcf5090aeb8>
# Group Input <bpy_struct, NodeGroupInput("Group Input") at 0x7fcf5090c008>
```

Answer (score 2):

Bpy ops seem to never return the thing they've created. The modifier is created attached to the active object, so to find it quickly use

```py
bpy.context.active_object.modifiers[-1].node_group
```

-1 works because you've just created the modifier so it's the last one in the group.  Replace -1 with `'GeometryNodes'` at other times.

If you use `'GeometryNodes'` be aware that it is possible for a give object ot have multiple geometry node modifiers, so you have to figure out if you have the right one.

If you don't know whether the active object has a Geometry Nodes modifier, than the name lookup will fail if it doesn't.  It will also fail if the user had changed the name of the modifier.

You can use

```py
next(m for m in C.active_object.modifiers if m.type=='NODES')
```

to get the first (the highest on the stack) geometry nodes modifier, or an error if there's no geonodes mods on the stack. You can also use

```py
next(m for m in C.active_object.modifiers if m.type=='NODES', None)
```

to get `None` instead of an error. Or you can use

```py
[m for m in C.active_object.modifiers if m.type=='NODES']
```

to get a list of all geonodes modifiers.

Comment: Thanks for the update Markus von Broady.